# fedora linux environment, select fails in mysql

Tags: mysql, c, linux

In c this code fails:

```
result = mysql_query(conn, "select username from golfer");
```

However, previously executed `MySQL_init` and `mysql_real_connect` successfully works.

There is nothing wrong with the code, it works perfectly when connecting to a different server. I can successfully execute the failing query from a terminal, i.e.,

```
MySQL> select username from golfer;
```

All the queries work great as long as I execute them from a terminal. So it appears the data base is set up correctly. I checked the following:

1. table User in db MySQL shows correct username and host.
2. table User in db MySQL shows localhost, correct user, correct password, and Select_priv = Y.

In data base MySQL, tables db, host, tables-priv and column-priv are identical in both servers. But the code fails when connecting to one server but not the other.

I do not know the error code coming back because it would take a substantial effort to get it. Therefore, is there any other permissions, whatever, that I should be looking at?

This is 5 year old code that has been working perfectly. Trying to port to new server. I looked at grants for username@host, It said:

```
grant all privileges on 'correct database'.* to correct 'username'@'localhost'
```

So, that looks right to me.

EDIT:
I am trying to get error code from failing MYSQL query. Code follows:

```
#define CANNOT_CONNECT 2

MYSQL *conn;
char *server = "localhost";
char *user = "myname";
char *password = "";
char *database = "golfprob";
int result = 10;
int error_num = 0;
int no_char;
char insert[70];

freopen("home/Dave/stderr.log", "w", stderr);
conn = mysql_init(NULL);

if (!mysql_real_connect(conn,server,user,password,0,NULL,0))
    return(CANNOT_CONNECT);            

noChar = sprintf(insert, "select username, password from golfer");
result = mysql_query(conn, insert);

if (result != 0)
{
    error_num = mysql_errno(conn);
    fprintf(stderr, "Query Failed: Error: %s\n", mysql_error(conn));
    fclose(stderr);
    mysqlL_close(conn);

    return(error_num);
}
```

The query fails.
Upon execution, error_num = 3 which is not a valid MySQL error code.
No output is printed on stderr. I'm not sure what display is stderr or if stderr makes any sense in this context.

As you have gathered, I am trying to write the error in text to a file.
No file is written anywhere. Please educate me as to why.

Important aspects of the environment:
Code is executing out of /var/www/cgi-bin in apache web server
Code is triggered by entry on web page, MS IE is browser.
computers are networked by intranet.

I welcome any insightful comments.
Thanks--

Comment: Thanks for responding, MQSQL versions are identical as well as the database engine. Also in response to SnakeDoc, thanks for responding but the problem is not in the code. It is probably something in the permissions. I tried to supply as much info as possible to avoid getting suggestions to look at things I have already looked at--thus avoiding tic-tacking back and forth in this forum. If that doesn't work, then I am out of luck.

Comment: @user3348464 First thing you should check is the error message you get when it fails and update your question with that. Right now you're telling us the query fails but you're not telling us what the exact error message is, which can be something vital to tell you how to solve or where the issue is at.

Comment: In the appropriate sense, what is different when executing a query from the command line as opposed to executing it from code?

Comment: Depends from where the application is running from, if it is using the socket or a different way to connect, etc. What is the MySQL error code and message you get by running the application?

Comment: @SnakeDoc if he posts the current error code and message he gets it will be easy to pin point what could be or perhaps he did that and already found out what the problem is.

Comment: It will take me a day or so to get the exact error code. This is old code and I have to recreate the environ.

Comment: Also, I understand what you mean by bits and pieces. Thanks for editing and making question much more readable. I will do better next time.

Comment: @SnakeDoc  I have the following code to find the MySQL error code:    will continue later--have to figure out formatting commands.

Comment: @DundasDave my java is much stronger than my c, but to me, your use of stderr seems suspect. It's a possibility whatever should be populating your log is not sending it to stderr, but rather stdout? Try replacing your stderr's with stdout and see what happens.

Comment: @DundasDave also, you should not try to close `stderr` or `stdout`, but rather your `freopen()` returns a pointer which is the file handle, so you need to assign that to a variable, then use that file handle later on to close it... so like: `logfile = freopen("/path/to/log.log", "w", stdout);`

Comment: I never did sql in C so not sure about the value of this comment but you don't have terminating comma on your query

Comment: "Query Failed: Error" ... What did it print ?

Comment: @nos There is no printout of any kind.

Comment: @EoiFirst  Thanks for responding. I think what you mean is that there is no terminating semi-colon for the statement containing the mysql_real_connect clause. If that is what you are commenting about, the terminating semi-colon is after the following return statement. If statements are not terminated per se.

Comment: that's called a `single selection if statement` :)

Comment: i think @EoiFirst was actually referring to the actual query being run. In java, for instance, `PreparedStatement` does not like a terminating ; in the query string... but `Statement` does prefer it.

Comment: @DundasDave at this point, your question may have fallen to the back pages of SO... and may not get the exposure it needs. I might suggest either creating a new question and narrowing it a bit to something like "why does my log not print the SQL error" and include your code, the proper tags, and a descriptive title for that question. Once you get that solved, then ask another question about why the query is not working, and include the new log that hopefully was solved from the previous question. This should help get your question(s) to the top of the SO list and with proper tags, exposure.

Comment: @SnakeDoc  That sounds like a good idea. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It now works. The following adjustments were key:<br>Adjusted seLinux privileges to "warning' vice "error" <br> The data base has to be owned by MYSQL, i.e., chown MySQL:mysql databse_name <br>

Comment: The above comment is void. <br><br>It now works. The following adjustments were key:<br>Adjusted seLinux privileges to "warning' vice "error" <br>  The directory where the data base resides has to be owned by MYSQL, i.e., chown mysql:mysql *.* <br> The directory has to have read, write, execute permissions, i.e., chmod 777 *.*  <br> I hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: see the comments that are posted with the question. (It is obvious I do not know how to use this forum).